# No RSA private key generated

Tags: php, openssl, rsa

I'm new in PHP and I followed this tutorial, https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/encryption-using-php-openssl/

Using the code below, there was no private.key file generated in my root folder. Is there something wrong? I'm running XAMPP on Windows 10 and I've set my environment variables to point to my XAMPP's openssl.cnf file.

```
function generate_public_private_keys() {

    $privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
        'private_key_bits' => 2048,      // Size of Key.
        'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    ));

    // Save the private key to private.key file. Never share this file with anyone.
    openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privateKey, 'private.key');

    // Generate the public key for the private key
    $a_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);

    // Save the public key in public.key file. Send this file to the person developing the ticket scanner app
    file_put_contents('public.key', $a_key['key']);

    // Free the private Key.
    openssl_free_key($privateKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking under your Xampp folder, like C:\xampp